# reading arguments for program from custom file and running that program with this arguments

Tags: string, bash, scripting, arguments, sh

all!

I need to read arguments from a file 'data' that consists of strings like:

```
-a -camb="1 0.5 1",diff="1 0 0" -q=5
-a -camb="0 1 0" -p -q -f=10
...
```

Next, that arguments must be passed to a program ./test within a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    ./test "$line"
done < "./data"
```

the problem is that "$line" is passed as argv[1] to ./test, and not as a sequence of argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]

How can I split the string line to several arguments? I.e. the ./test must takes argv[1], argv[2], and so?

Note, that -camb="1 0.5 1",diff="1 0 0" must be as whole argument, argv[2]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use eval for this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    eval "./test $line"
done < "./data"
```

There's a big warning here, however: eval may do more interpretation of the file contents than you want.  For example, if it contains any I/O redirects (e.g. `>somefile`), they *will* be applied.  Similarly, `$variable` *will* be substituted, `; somecommand` *will* be executed as a separate command, etc.  Basically, if the contents of the data file aren't clean enough, you can get some unexpected and potentially dangerous results.

Answer (score 1):

The quotes are [literal, not syntactic](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments#Quoting), which means they won't be handled the same way as on the shell. But you can handle them by setting them in an array:

```
$ params(){
    for param in "$@"
    do
        echo "$param"
    done
}
$ while IFS= read -r line
do
    declare -a par="($line)"
    params "${par[@]}"
    echo
done < data
-a
-camb=1 0.5 1,diff=1 0 0
-q=5

-a
-camb=0 1 0
-p
-q
-f=10
```

PS: [Don't use `eval`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Comment: @IObO:  Why does this work?  What is IFS= ?  Why use read -r? Thx

Comment: For details about how it works, there are excellent articles about the keywords ([`IFS`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS), [`while read`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), [parameters](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters)) and the Bash `man` page. If you want to really learn Bash, those pages and all the links from there are worth their printed weight in gold.

Comment: Thx for the links.  I now understand your script except for one thing: Why does your declare statement break the line variable on dash symbols?  I'm baffled by that.

Comment: It doesn't :) First, `"($line)"` is expanded to e.g. `(-a -camb=0\ 1\ 0 -p -q -f=10)`, and then `IFS` (space+tab+newline by default) is used to split that into an array. Escaped characters like `\ ` are not split.

Comment: But IFS is set to null in the while statement.  Isn't it still null for the declare statement?

Comment: It is, but as far as I understand for this kind of statements Bash uses the *default value* of `$' \t\n'`.

Comment: OK, and then the blanks inside the double quotes per section 6.7 of bash ref which says: "These subscripts differ only when the word appears within double quotes. If the word is double-quoted, ${name[*]} expands to a single word with the value of each array member separated by the first character of the IFS variable."  Now I'm going to search for documentation on the IFS value in the declare statement.

Comment: I've determined (by using echo "IFS" | cat -vte) that the setting of IFS to null in the while statement is not retained inside the do.  I can't figure out why so I'm going to post a new question.

Comment: While preparing my new question I found something that lead me to bash ref 3.7.4 which says "The environment for any simple command or function may be augmented temporarily by prefixing it with parameter assignments, as described in Shell Parameters. These assignment statements affect only the environment seen by that command."  This explains why IFS is different for the read command and the declare statement.